# Anti-Theft Mobile CPU

Tags: android, iphone, cpu, tee

The newest Android phones use the Qualcomm Snapdragon 855 chipset with its TrustZone/TEE.  The Android OS makes sure that a stolen phone, in its assembled form, is not usable.

Does Trustzone further prevent the CPU from being removed from a stolen phone and used in any way?  I see how Qualcomm could lock the CPU (e.g., with a PIN or a fingerprint), but I also see how this could be dangerous for hardware development so I suspect that Qualcomm would allow some reset/unlock mechanism.

I'm basically wondering if there is any phone with anti-theft features preventing the CPU from having any stolen value.  If not Android, what about iPhone?

Comment: How do you remove a CPU from a phone?

Comment: Melt the solder and pull?  Also, an in-place CPU reset might be possible, but I can't find security info from Qualcomm...thus my question.

Comment: Trustzone does not provide hardware security.

Comment: Then my question is simply "Does any phone provide hardware (specifically CPU) security?"  If the answer is no, that would mean that all stolen phones can be wiped/reset, with no replacement parts needed (though disassembly and programming might be needed), to work at least with WiFi.  OK, maybe that's true, but I wish someone would provide a formal answer.

Comment: Removed TPM modules form PC MBs. They still worked fine...